# Sinch SMS verification SINVerificationErrorDomain Code=3

Tags: ios, sinch

```
id<SINVerification> verification =
[SINVerification SMSVerificationWithApplicationKey:SINCH_Key phoneNumber:phoneNumber];

[verification initiateWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"sucess");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error : %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

This is the error message:

> Error Domain=SINVerificationErrorDomain Code=3 "Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=403 "Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=40303 "Authorization requirement not met." UserInfo=0x7f838254a420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization requirement not met.}" UserInfo=0x7f8382550270 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=40303 "Authorization requirement not met." UserInfo=0x7f838254a420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization requirement not met.}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f838253c240 "Authorization requirement not met."}" UserInfo=0x7f83824a7a40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=403 "Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=40303 "Authorization requirement not met." UserInfo=0x7f838254a420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization requirement not met.}" UserInfo=0x7f8382550270 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=40303 "Authorization requirement not met." UserInfo=0x7f838254a420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization requirement not met.}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f838253c240 "Authorization requirement not met."}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8382556cc0 "Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=40303 "Authorization requirement not met." UserInfo=0x7f838254a420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization requirement not met.}"}

I am sure that my phone number and app key is correct. I have tried to set `dashboard->verification` to public and application but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: My phone number is using international format. i.e. @"+[country code][phone number]"

Comment: Did you find any solution. I also stuck in a same problem

Comment: @SauravNagpal I hope it's not too late to reply you. I fixed the issue by going to Sinch dashboard -> select you app ->Under verification, change Authorization from APPLICATION to PUBLIC.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the issue by going to Sinch dashboard -> select you app ->Under verification, change Authorization from APPLICATION to PUBLIC.